# how to redirect the error message of SqlException in asp.net to ShowMessage.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net C# web application. I used try catch exception but error message does not show.

My code:

```
protected void Btn_insert_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // my code
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        if (sqlEx.ErrorCode == 2601)
        {
            Session.Add("Msg_", " you insert duplicate record " + sqlEx.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx", false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Session.Add("Msg_", "error msg" + ex.Message);
        Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when this code:

```
 Session.Add("Msg_", " you insert duplicate record " + sqlEx.Message);
 Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx", false);
```

is inside `{}`, the error message does not redirect to `ShowMessage.aspx` and when is outside of `{}`:

```
 catch (SqlException sqlEx)
 {
     if (sqlEx.ErrorCode == 2601)
     {
     }

     Session.Add("Msg_", " you insert duplicate record " + sqlEx.Message);
     Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx", false);
 }
```

the error of SQL Server shows, too:

> You inserted a duplicate record
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_sh_dadnameh'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_dadnameh_ghesti'. The statement has been terminated.

I don't want to show the SQL Server error. I want to show only the "You inserted a duplicate record"

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just throw the exception from SqlException.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on exception messages to display to users. They can change without warning. Instead, catch specific exceptions, and hardcode the text you display to your users based on what your application can gleam from the exception, such as checking the error code.

Comment: please more detail.

Comment: I want use sql Exception for specific and catch Exception for generic error

Comment: The proper way to redirect is to do this after calling redirect because using "false" as the parameter continues to run the rest of the page, it does not redirect at that line: `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
`

Comment: `SqlException` has an `Errors` property.I think you want the `Number` property on the `SqlError`, not `ErrorCode`. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror(v=vs.110).aspx